# Excessive sort memory grant

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, memory-grant

Why is this simple query granted so much memory?

```
-- Demo table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TID integer IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    FilterMe integer NOT NULL,
    SortMe integer NOT NULL,
    Unused nvarchar(max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Test_TID
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TID)
);
GO
-- 100,000 example rows
INSERT dbo.Test WITH (TABLOCKX)
    (FilterMe, SortMe)
SELECT TOP (100 * 1000)
    CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 1000,
    CHECKSUM(NEWID())
FROM sys.all_columns AS AC1
CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS AC2;
GO    
-- Query
SELECT
    T.TID,
    T.FilterMe,
    T.SortMe,
    T.Unused
FROM dbo.Test AS T 
WHERE 
    T.FilterMe = 567
ORDER BY 
    T.SortMe;
```

For an estimated 50 rows, the optimizer reserves almost 500 MB for the sort:

[image: Estimated plan]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is a **bug** in SQL Server (from 2008 to 2014 inclusive).

My bug report is **[here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32909110-cardinality-estimation-error-with-pushed-predicate)**.

The filtering condition is pushed down into the scan operator as a residual predicate, but the memory granted for the sort is erroneously calculated based on the **pre-filter cardinality estimate**.

To illustrate the issue, we can use *(undocumented and unsupported)* trace flag 9130 to prevent the Filter from being **pushed down into the scan** operator. The memory granted to the sort is now correctly based on the estimated cardinality of the Filter output, not the scan:

```
SELECT
    T.TID,
    T.FilterMe,
    T.SortMe,
    T.Unused
FROM dbo.Test AS T 
WHERE 
    T.FilterMe = 567
ORDER BY 
    T.SortMe
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9130); -- Not for production systems!
```

[image: Estimated plan]

For a **production system**, steps will need to be taken to **avoid** the problematic plan shape (a filter pushed into a scan with a sort on another column). One way to do this is to provide an index on the filter condition and/or to provide the required sort order.

```
-- Index on the filter condition only
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_Test_FilterMe
ON dbo.Test (FilterMe);
```

With this index in place, the desired memory grant for the sort is only **928KB**:

[image: With filter index]

Going further, the following index can avoid the sort completely (**zero** memory grant):

```
-- Provides filtering and sort order
-- nvarchar(max) column deliberately not INCLUDEd
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_Test_FilterMe_SortMe
ON dbo.Test (FilterMe, SortMe);
```

[image: With filter and sort index]

Tested and bug confirmed on the following builds of SQL Server x64 Developer Edition:

```
2014   : 12.00.2430 (RTM CU4)
2012   : 11.00.5556 (SP2 CU3)
2008R2 : 10.50.6000 (SP3)
2008   : 10.00.6000 (SP4)
```

This was **fixed** in [SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3182545). The release notes include the following:

> VSTS bug number 8024987
>   Table scans and index scans with push down predicate tend to overestimate memory grant for the parent operator.

Tested and confirmed fixed on:

- `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) Developer Edition`
- `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU3) 12.0.5538.0 (X64) Developer Edition`

Both CE models.

Answer (score 5):

From SQL 2012 onwards you *could* look for a large discrepancy between `SerialRequiredMemory` and `SerialDesiredMemory`, eg something like this:

```
-- Search plan cache for Memory Grant issues
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp

-- Collect more info about the plan here if required, eg usecounts, objtype etc, 
SELECT IDENTITY( INT, 1, 1 ) rowId, query_plan
INTO #tmp
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp WITH(NOLOCK)
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)
GO


;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
    rowId,
    query_plan,
    m.c.value ('@SerialRequiredMemory', 'INT' ) AS SerialRequiredMemory,
    m.c.value ('@SerialDesiredMemory', 'INT' ) AS SerialDesiredMemory

FROM #tmp t
    CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes ( '//*:MemoryGrantInfo[@SerialDesiredMemory[. > 0]]' ) m(c)
), cte2 AS (
SELECT *,
    CAST( CAST( SerialDesiredMemory AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) / CAST( SerialRequiredMemory AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) Desired_to_Required_ratio
FROM cte
)
SELECT TOP 20
    rowId,
    query_plan,
    SerialRequiredMemory SerialRequiredMemory_KB,
    SerialDesiredMemory SerialDesiredMemory_KB,
    CAST( SerialRequiredMemory / 1024. AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) SerialRequiredMemory_MB,
    CAST( SerialDesiredMemory / 1024. AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) SerialDesiredMemory_MB,
    Desired_to_Required_ratio
FROM cte2
WHERE Desired_to_Required_ratio > 100
ORDER BY Desired_to_Required_ratio DESC
```

Some further notes on these new attributes [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/memory-grant-execution-plan-statistics/).  This query is a bit rough and ready but did pick up the excessive sort query from my SQL Server 2014 dev box with a ratio of 975.47 plus a couple of other eye-popping plans.  The 'normal' ratio (at least from my limited testing) seems to be ~1.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help.  I thought I would send an updated version of the above query that we found helpful.

```
-- Search plan cache for Memory Grant issues
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp

-- Collect more info about the plan here if required, eg usecounts, objtype etc, 
SELECT IDENTITY( INT, 1, 1 ) rowId, query_plan, db = DB_NAME(CAST(pa.value AS int))
INTO #tmp
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp WITH(NOLOCK)
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle)
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(cp.plan_handle) pa 
    WHERE pa.attribute = 'dbid' 
GO

;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
    rowId,
    query_plan,
    m.c.value ('@SerialRequiredMemory', 'INT' ) AS SerialRequiredMemory,
    m.c.value ('@SerialDesiredMemory', 'INT' ) AS SerialDesiredMemory,
    db
FROM #tmp t
    CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes ( '//*:MemoryGrantInfo[@SerialDesiredMemory[. > 0]]' ) m(c)
), cte2 AS (
SELECT *,
    CAST( CAST( SerialDesiredMemory AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) / CAST( SerialRequiredMemory AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) Desired_to_Required_ratio
FROM cte
)
SELECT TOP 20
    rowId,
    query_plan,
    SerialRequiredMemory SerialRequiredMemory_KB,
    SerialDesiredMemory SerialDesiredMemory_KB,
    CAST( SerialRequiredMemory / 1024. AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) SerialRequiredMemory_MB,
    CAST( SerialDesiredMemory / 1024. AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) SerialDesiredMemory_MB,
    Desired_to_Required_ratio,
    db
FROM cte2
WHERE Desired_to_Required_ratio > 100
ORDER BY Desired_to_Required_ratio DESC
```